# Converting flatfile to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, flat-file

I need to convert a flat file to a JSON file in Java.

My flat file looks like this:

```
customerInfo.firstName=abc
customerInfo.lastName=aaa
customerInfo.nickNames.0.name=bbb
customerInfo.nickNames.0.meaning=ccc
```

Here is the piece of code I am using:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = null;
try {
    //obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/flatfileex.txt"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/flatfileex.txt")));;
    String flattenedJson = JsonFlattener.flatten(jsonObject.toJSONString());
    System.out.println(flattenedJson);
} catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using jsonflattener dependency for the above code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting error while parsing the file Unexcexpected character [c] at position 0. How to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, but your INPUT isnt json. Why do you want to use a JSON parser to read non-json input? That is plain text. You need to write code to parse it, according to the "semantics" that are baked into your proprietary "format" within the text file. Then you can create JSONObjects from those objects, and write those as JSON.

Comment: @GhostCat Is there any way we can convert flatfile to json then i.e. text file to json without using objectmapper and some skeleton object schema?

Comment: If you had a FlatFile you could parse it with something like jFFP and then proceed to serialize it with Jackson or something to get to a JSON, but you don't have a FlatFile. You have some weird set of properties, so first thing that comes to mind is `java.util.Properties`, but then you'd end up with variables named `0` which is not possible in Java because of naming conventions. Long story short, your input data is trash and this is precisely why data is exchanged in formats like XML or JSON, to avoid parsing non-sense. You'll probably have to write a custom parser for the deserialization.

Comment: And then when you have the correct Java Object representation of your input, you can go for the next step that is serialization into JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Your input file looks like a Java properties file, so you could try this:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try (InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("content.txt")){
    prop.load(inputStream);
    String contentAsJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(prop);
    System.out.print(contentAsJson);
} catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
}
```

If your file contains

```
customerInfo.firstName=abc
customerInfo.lastName=aaa
customerInfo.nickNames.0.name=bbb
customerInfo.nickNames.0.meaning=ccc
```

It will print

```
{"customerInfo.lastName":"aaa","customerInfo.firstName":"abc","customerInfo.nickNames.0.name":"bbb","customerInfo.nickNames.0.meaning":"ccc"}
```

I guess that from here you can use `json-flattener`.

Comment: What about variables named `0`? It's gonna blow up as soon as you deserialize it into the object it represents. If you want to go this way it already needs to be stored in the JSON as an array in order to not cause issues down the road.

Comment: customerInfo.nickNames.0.name i want to convert it into json array not a property

Comment: Do they actually want a POJO to represent this? AFAIT the question is how to transform that input into JSON.

Comment: Oh, it looks like what you want is something to `unflatten` your JSON. You can use `JsonUnflattener.unflatten` for that.

Comment: unflatten would do the trick, if you replace in contentAsJson per regex \.(\d+)\. with \[$1\].